# How to make a prefilled doughnut in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, chart.js

I want to create a prefilled doughnut using chart.js like the picture below.[image]

[This doughnut is made of using SVG](https://openstudio.redhat.com/scratch-made-svg-donut-pie-charts-in-html5/).

[But chart.JS cannot support SVG's](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/notes/comparison.html)

So Is there any way to create a doughnut-like the Image above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Have you taken a look at http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html

Comment: I used doughnuts from chart.js in some of my works.But Now I want a doughnut with a prefilled grey line where I want to show the main doughnut's data over the prefilled doughnut line.Here is the link where the examples are given openstudio.redhat.com/… – Abdullah Al Mamun

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun Please check answer. Isn't it that what you asked for?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ["1", "2"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [105, 20],
    backgroundColor: ['da5d78', 'gray'],
  }]
};

var options = {
  rotation: 0,
  cutoutPercentage: 85,
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  }
}

Chart.Doughnut(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

**See how it looks on working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cqkj6z5/)**

See [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html) for explanations of options (`cutoutPercentage`, `rotation` etc).